# Console : background color fills line when exceeding buffer

Tags: c#, console, command-prompt

I was printing alot to the windows-console in different colors for testing, and setting the text and backgroundcolor at random. When the lines exceed the console-buffer, the background color is set to the entire line. Here is an example in C#:

```
static void Main( String[] args )
{
    Console.BufferHeight = 16;

    foreach( var i in Enumerable.Range( 0 , Console.BufferHeight + 3 ) )
    { 
        var fgColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
        var bgColor = Console.BackgroundColor;
        var tst = i % 2 == 0;
        Console.ForegroundColor = tst ? ConsoleColor.White : ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.BackgroundColor = tst ? ConsoleColor.Black : ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine( $"{i} HELLO WORLD" );
        Console.ForegroundColor = fgColor;
        Console.BackgroundColor = bgColor;
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

[image]

I already set the buffer to its max buffer size (16 bit), but this application will print several million lines in the future.

Is there a fix for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I already set the buffer to its max buffer size (16 bit), but this application will print several million lines in the future.

Then I think you mean `Int16.MaxValue` instead of 16.

Anyway, to fix your issue, just restore the color **before** writing the end of line character:

```
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, Console.BufferHeight + 3))
{
    var fgColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
    var bgColor = Console.BackgroundColor;
    var tst = i % 2 == 0;
    Console.ForegroundColor = tst ? ConsoleColor.White : ConsoleColor.Black;
    Console.BackgroundColor = tst ? ConsoleColor.Black : ConsoleColor.Yellow;
    Console.Write($"{i} HELLO WORLD");
    Console.ForegroundColor = fgColor;
    Console.BackgroundColor = bgColor;
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i didnt think of the newline character, this works! I actually meant 16 as an arbitrary small number for testing

Comment: This was exactly my answer I was about to post :-)
Kevin was a few minutes quicker ...